# Download and insert salt string inside wordpress wp-config.php with Bash

Tags: wordpress, bash, sed

How can I insert the content of the variable $SALT **in a specific point (line or string)** of a file like wp-contet.php from wordpress using Bash script?

```
SALT=$(curl -L https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/)
```

Comment: do you mean parsing that exact file (wp-config.php) looking for the defines of the AUTH_KEY, SECURE_AUTH_KEY ...etc and replace those by the downloaded salt?

Comment: I was thinking about choosing a specific line or a specific string to make the insertion...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not an expert at parsing text files in bash but you should delete the lines that define the things you're downloading from the wordpress salt and then insert the variable at the end... something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

SALT=$(curl -L https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/)
STRING='put your unique phrase here'
printf '%s\n' "g/$STRING/d" a "$SALT" . w | ed -s wp-config.php
```

OK, now it's fixed... it should look for where the salt is supposed to go and it will replace it with the info retrieved from https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/

Comment: Is there a way to make this insertion in a specific point of the wp-config.php file?

Comment: @Roger in this case thats irrelevant because its a configuration file and its all defines. There's probably a way of doing it like that but as I said,... I'm not very good with bash. You should look on some info on sed and awk which are bash's specific parsing tools. if it's a script you'll be using for different files you could pass the words as arguments. Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: @Roger, no prob... also I changed the example a little bit so it deletes the lines which contain 'put your unique phrase here' which of course are the lines you would usually replace by hand in wp-config.php. If you're using the portuguese version of wordpress (I assume there is one because many of my clients use spanish versions) just replace that by the phrase you find there. The salt will be added at the end of the file...which I admit is not pretty... maybe there's a way to download it the same way it is when you visit the salt's url with curl...I don't really know that. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Roger ... ok now I nailed it ;). It should look for the specific lines containing 'put your unique phrase here' and replace that for the curl data

Comment: Thank you, @la_fOka, you really did it! Would you mind to tell a bit of what is happening here? `printf '%s\n' "g/$STRING/d" a "$SALT" . w | ed -s wp-config.php `

Comment: you're just piping a command to ed through printf telling it to look for the $STRING and adding the salt at the end. the -s is used because you're passing input this way. Check ed's man to figure exactly how it works. I'm not english speaker myself so I kind of suck at tech explanations.srry, but good luck!

Comment: @Roger The first thing going on here in the printf statement is the '%s\n'. This takes the string to the right ("g/$STRING/d" a "$SALT" . w ) and appends a newline to the end (\n). Now we need to tackle that string to the right ("g/$STRING/d" a "$SALT" . w ) First, 'g' enables the "global" option. Meaning it will take a single pass and create a mark for each instance of the $STRING found in wp-config.php. The '/' is a separator between options (simply put).

Comment: The 'd' option tells the regular expression engine in ED to delete the entire line where the STRING is found (in our case "put your unique phrase here"). Now the pointer (cursor) in ED (a linux based line editor), is placed on the very next line after the deleted line. This is where the value of this command comes from. This behavior in ED of placing the current pointer at the begining of the very next line is critical.

Comment: Because the very next ED command 'a' tells ED to add whatever string that comes next to the file buffer at the current pointer (wherever the cursor is placed). In our case, this is the SALT. The '.' tells ED that no more text is coming and to wait for the next command, 'w'. This 'w' will write the contents of the buffer to disk. Lastly, this entire "script" is piped into ED. Hope this helps out!

Comment: This is what I get when I do it, it's not escaping the salts correctly: -bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: This answer requires the phrase `'put your unique phrase here'` be present in the config file.  If it has already been replaced and you want to change the salts/keys again, this will no longer work.

Answer (score 6):

This version defines new keys if none exist, and also replaces existing keys:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -name wp-config.php -print | while read line
do 
    curl http://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ > wp_keys.txt
    sed -i.bak -e '/put your unique phrase here/d' -e \
    '/AUTH_KEY/d' -e '/SECURE_AUTH_KEY/d' -e '/LOGGED_IN_KEY/d' -e '/NONCE_KEY/d' -e \
    '/AUTH_SALT/d' -e '/SECURE_AUTH_SALT/d' -e '/LOGGED_IN_SALT/d' -e '/NONCE_SALT/d' $line
    cat wp_keys.txt >> $line
    rm wp_keys.txt
done
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have [`csplit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/csplit.html) available, you can split the original wp-config.php file either side of the salt definitions, download new salts, then cat back together.  This keeps the PHP `define()` statements at the same location in wp-config.php instead of than moving them to a different location within the file:

```
# Download new salts
curl "https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/" -o salts

# Split wp-config.php into 3 on the first and last definition statements
csplit wp-config.php '/AUTH_KEY/' '/NONCE_SALT/+1'

# Recombine the first part, the new salts and the last part
cat xx00 salts xx02 > wp-config.php

# Tidy up
rm salts xx00 xx01 xx02
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using sed?

```
cat wp-config.php | sed 's/old_string/new_string/g' > wp-config.php
```

Comment: This was my first attempt but it didn't work because the salt string has a lot of unescaped garbage...

Comment: besides he needs the rest of the file so it should be with '>>' instead of '>'

Comment: In order to use "sed" I have to find a way to somehow escape all the garbage that comes in the salt... Till now I haven't found a good way to do that.

Comment: Is there a risk this may truncate the file before it is read?  Probably safer to use `sed 's/old_string/new_string/g' -i wp-config.php` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think I got this one! its a bash script using only commands normally available at the command prompt and it does -everything- (assuming httpd is your web user) except create the databases. here you go.

```
#!/bin/bash

# wordpress latest auto-install script, by alienation 24 jan 2013. run as root.
# usage: ~/wp-install alien /hsphere/local/home/alien/nettrip.org alien_wpdbname alien_wpdbusername p@sSw0rd
# ( wp-install shell-user folder db-name db-user-name db-user-pw )

# download wordpress to temporary area
cd /tmp
rm -rf tmpwp
mkdir tmpwp
cd tmpwp
wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
tar -xvzpf latest.tar.gz

# copy wordpress to where it will live, and go there, removing index placeholder if there is one
mv wordpress/* $2
cd $2
rm index.html

# create config from sample, replacing salt example lines with a real salt from online generator
grep -A 1 -B 50 'since 2.6.0' wp-config-sample.php > wp-config.php
wget -O - https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ >> wp-config.php
grep -A 50 -B 3 'Table prefix' wp-config-sample.php >> wp-config.php

# put the appropriate db info in place of placeholders in our new config file
replace 'database_name_here' $3 -- wp-config.php
replace 'username_here' $4 -- wp-config.php
replace 'password_here' $5 -- wp-config.php

# change file ownership and permissions according to ideal at http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#File_Permissions
touch .htaccess
chown $1:httpd .htaccess
chown -R $1:httpd *
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
chmod -R 770 wp-content
chmod -R g-w wp-admin wp-includes wp-content/plugins
chmod g+w .htaccess

# thats it!
echo ALL DONE
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Answer (score 1):

I built a simple CLI for just that. Try it out. It's called `[WP-Salts-Update-CLI][1]`.

## [WP-Salts-Update-CLI](https://github.com/ahmadawais/WP-Salts-Update-CLI)

`WPSUCLI` downloads new salts from the WP API and replaces them with the ones in your wp-config.php file for every site on your server.

### ⚡️ Installation

Open command line terminal (I prefer iTerm2) and run the following command.

`bash
sudo wget -qO wpsucli https://git.io/vykgu && sudo chmod +x ./wpsucli && sudo install ./wpsucli /usr/local/bin/wpsucli`

This command will perform the following actions:

- Use sudo permissions
- Use wget to download `WPSUCLI` and rename it to `wpsucli`
- Make the `wpsucli` executable
- Install `wpsucli` inside /usr/local/bin/ folder.

### Usage

Just run `wpsucli` and it will update the salts for every `wp-config.php` file on your server or PC.

Answer (score 1):

This is the bash script that I came up with that works on my Ubuntu server.  I modified the examples from above.

Its a bit of brute force in that it will only replace the 8 keys that currently are required and expects the server to return exactly the same length key every time.  The script works well for my use case so I thought I would share it.

```
CONFIG_FILE=wp-config.php
SALT=$(curl -L https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/)
SRC="define('AUTH_KEY'"; DST=$(echo $SALT|cat|grep -o define\(\'AUTH_KEY\'.\\{70\\}); sed -i "/$SRC/c$DST" $CONFIG_FILE
SRC="define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY'"; DST=$(echo $SALT|cat|grep -o define\(\'SECURE_AUTH_KEY\'.\\{70\\}); sed -i "/$SRC/c$DST" $CONFIG_FILE
SRC="define('LOGGED_IN_KEY'"; DST=$(echo $SALT|cat|grep -o define\(\'LOGGED_IN_KEY\'.\\{70\\}); sed -i "/$SRC/c$DST" $CONFIG_FILE
SRC="define('NONCE_KEY'"; DST=$(echo $SALT|cat|grep -o define\(\'NONCE_KEY\'.\\{70\\}); sed -i "/$SRC/c$DST" $CONFIG_FILE
SRC="define('AUTH_SALT'"; DST=$(echo $SALT|cat|grep -o define\(\'AUTH_SALT\'.\\{70\\}); sed -i "/$SRC/c$DST" $CONFIG_FILE
SRC="define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT'"; DST=$(echo $SALT|cat|grep -o define\(\'SECURE_AUTH_SALT\'.\\{70\\}); sed -i "/$SRC/c$DST" $CONFIG_FILE
SRC="define('LOGGED_IN_SALT'"; DST=$(echo $SALT|cat|grep -o define\(\'LOGGED_IN_SALT\'.\\{70\\}); sed -i "/$SRC/c$DST" $CONFIG_FILE
SRC="define('NONCE_SALT'"; DST=$(echo $SALT|cat|grep -o define\(\'NONCE_SALT\'.\\{70\\}); sed -i "/$SRC/c$DST" $CONFIG_FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the accepted solution:

```
#!/bin/sh
SALT=$(curl -L https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/)
STRING='put your unique phrase here'
printf '%s\n' "g/$STRING/d" a "$SALT" . w | ed -s wp-config.php
```

However it does not work perfectly as for some reason it induces the SALTS to "move down" 1 line in the wp-config.php file each time it is used... it is not ideal if you are going to change SALTS automatically like every week, months with cron for example...

A better solution for me was to create a little function that I call in my script.
This function creates a file with the SALTS (deletes it at the end), deletes every lines containing one of the SALTS then just inserts the SALTS contained in the file in place of the initial SALTS.
This works perfectly.

```
fct_update_salts() {
    # Requires website name as target

    curl http://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ > ~/SALTS.txt

    var_initial_path1=`pwd`
    cd ~ #going to home directory

    # This scripts eliminates successively all SALT entries, replaces the last one by XXX as a marker, places SALTS.txt, below XXX and deletes XXX
    sudo sed -i "/SECURE_AUTH_KEY/d" $1/wp-config.php
    sudo sed -i "/LOGGED_IN_KEY/d" $1/wp-config.php
    sudo sed -i "/NONCE_KEY/d" $1/wp-config.php
    sudo sed -i "/AUTH_SALT/d" $1/wp-config.php
    sudo sed -i "/SECURE_AUTH_SALT/d" $1/wp-config.php
    sudo sed -i "/LOGGED_IN_SALT/d" $1/wp-config.php
    sudo sed -i "/NONCE_SALT/d" $1/wp-config.php
    sudo sed -i "/AUTH_KEY/cXXX" $1/wp-config.php
    sudo sed -i '/XXX/r SALTS.txt' $1/wp-config.php
    sudo sed -i "/XXX/d" $1/wp-config.php
    echo "SALTS REPLACED BY:"
    echo "====================="
    cat ~/SALTS.txt
    sudo rm -rf ~/SALTS.txt
    cd $var_initial_path1
}
```

The function is to be called in the script like this:

```
# Reset SALTS
fct_update_salts $SITE_PATH
```

Where $SITE_PATH="/var/www/html/YOUR_WEBSITE" or whatever path works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was challenged with the same issue.  Here is the script I wrote to replace the salts and keys from ones downloaded from WordPress.  You can use it at any time to replace them if/when needed.  I run it as sudo, and the script tests for that.  If you use an account that can download to the directory and make updates to the wp-config.php file, then you can delete that part of the script.

```
#!/bin/sh
# update-WordPress-Salts: Updates WordPress Salts
# written by Wayne Woodward 2017

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: update-WordPress-Salts directory"
    exit
fi

if [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]; then
  echo "Please run as root (sudo)"
  exit
fi

WPPATH=$1

# Update the salts in the config file

# Download salts from WordPress and save them locally
curl http://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ > /var/www/$WPPATH/wp-keys.txt

# Iterate through each "Saltname" and append 1 to it
# For a couple names that may match twice like "AUTH_KEY" adds extra 1s to the end
# But that is OK as when this deletes the lines, it uses the same matching pattern
# (Smarter people may fix this)
for SALTNAME in AUTH_KEY SECURE_AUTH_KEY LOGGED_IN_KEY NONCE_KEY AUTH_SALT SECURE_AUTH_SALT LOGGED_IN_SALT NONCE_SALT
do
   sed -i -e "s/$SALTNAME/${SALTNAME}1/g" /var/www/$WPPATH/wp-config.php
done

# Find the line that has the updated AUTH_KEY1 name
# This is so we can insert the file in the same area
line=$(sed -n '/AUTH_KEY1/{=;q}' /var/www/$WPPATH/wp-config.php)

# Insert the file from the WordPress API that we saved into the configuration
sed -i -e "${line}r /var/www/$WPPATH/wp-keys.txt" /var/www/$WPPATH/wp-config.php

# Itererate through the old keys and remove them from the file
for SALTNAME in AUTH_KEY SECURE_AUTH_KEY LOGGED_IN_KEY NONCE_KEY AUTH_SALT SECURE_AUTH_SALT LOGGED_IN_SALT NONCE_SALT
do
   sed -i -e "/${SALTNAME}1/d" /var/www/$WPPATH/wp-config.php
done

# Delete the file downloaded from Wordpress
rm /var/www/$WPPATH/wp-keys.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Many of the answers rely on the phrase `'put your unique phrase here'` being present in the file, so they do not work when you want to change salts after the first time.  There are also some that remove the old definitions and append the new ones at the end.  While that does work, it's nice to keep the definitions where you would expect them, right after the comment documenting them.  My solution addresses those issues.

I made a few attempts with sed, perl and regex, but there are special characters in the salts and the rest of the config file that tend to mess things up.  I ended up using grep to search the document for the unique comment structure that opens and closes the salt definition block, which has the following format:

```
/**#@+
 <comment documentation>
 */
<salt definitions>

/**#@-*/
```

Note that if that comment structure is removed or altered, this will no longer work.  Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

# Set Default Settings:
file='wp-config.php'

# set up temporary files with automatic removal:
trap "rm -f $file_start $file_end $salt" 0 1 2 3 15
file_start=$(mktemp) || exit 1
file_end=$(mktemp) || exit 1
salt=$(mktemp) || exit 1

function find_line {
# returns the first line number in the file which contains the text
# program exits if text is not found
# $1 : text to search for
# $2 : file in which to search
# $3 (optional) : line at which to start the search
line=$(tail -n +${3:-1} $2 | grep -nm 1 $1 | cut -f1 -d:)
[ -z "$line" ] && exit 1
echo $(($line + ${3:-1} - 1))
}

line=$(find_line "/**#@+" "$file")
line=$(find_line "\*/" "$file" "$line")
head -n $line $file > $file_start
line=$(find_line "/**#@-\*/" "$file" "$line")
tail -n +$line $file > $file_end
curl -Ls https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ > $salt
(cat $file_start $salt; echo; cat $file_end) > $file

exit 0
```

Strings containing single asterisks, such as `"*/"` and `"/**#@-*/"` want to expand to directory lists, so that is why those asterisks are escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure bash approach. This does not depend on wordpress.org.

I converted the original [wp_generate_password()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_password/) function used by WordPress to [generate salt](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_salt/).

```bash
    #!/bin/bash
    
    set -e
    
    #
    # Generates a random password drawn from the defined set of characters.
    # Inspired by WordPress function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_password/
    #
    # Parameters
    # ----------
    # $length
    #   (ing) (Optional) Length of password to generate.
    #   Default value: 12
    # $special_chars
    #   (bool) (Optional) Whether to include standard special characters.
    #   Default value: true
    # $extra_special_chars
    #   (bool) (Optional) Whether to include other special characters. Used when generating secret keys and salts.
    #   Default value: false
    #
    function wp_generate_password() {
      # Args
      length="$(test $1 && echo $1 || echo 12 )"
      special_chars="$(test $2 && echo $2 || echo 1 )"
      extra_special_chars="$(test $3 && echo $3 || echo 0 )"
    
      chars='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
      [[ $special_chars != 0 ]] && chars="$chars"'!@#$%^&*()'
      [[ $extra_special_chars != 0 ]] && chars="$chars"'-_ []{}<>~`+=,.;:/?|'
    
      password='';
      for i in $(seq 1 $length); do
        password="${password}${chars:$(( RANDOM % ${#chars} )):1}"
      done
    
      echo "$password"
    }
```

You can then just run `SALT="$(wp_generate_password 64 1 1)"`.

## Update

I just published a [standalone script to generate WP salt values](https://github.com/timofey-drozhzhin/wp-generate-salt). You can generate the salt values by running `./wp-generate-salt.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

If the wordpress.org API generated SALT values are not necessary for your use case, you can use the `pwgen` to generate keys on the server and insert those into wp-config.php.

```
for i in {1..8} ;do unique_key="`pwgen -1 -s 64`";sudo sed -i "0,/put your unique phrase here/s/put your unique phrase here/$unique_key/" /srv/www/wordpress/wp-config.php; done
```

You may need to fix the ownership of the file after using sudo. You can use a command similar to this for changing the ownership.

```
chown www-data:www-data /srv/www/wordpress/wp-config.php
```