# Copy from url and replace

Tags: bash

I am trying to automate wordpress install with a bash script.How can i replace the `Authentication Unique Keys and Salts` with the ones from  https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ automatically with bash.

Regards

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a different set for each install?

Comment: @TomFenech `https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/` automatically generate a different set each time

Comment: @user2650277 What have you tried so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download and insert salt string inside wordpress wp-config.php with Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233398/download-and-insert-salt-string-inside-wordpress-wp-config-php-with-bash)

Answer (score 1):

i found the answer to my question on stackoverflow itself

Here is it --> [Download and insert salt string inside wordpress wp-config.php with Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233398/download-and-insert-salt-string-inside-wordpress-wp-config-php-with-bash)